# Queue Implementation

Tags: java, queue

First time I'm using stackexchange. I'm in 8th standard. I tried to implement Queue in Java. I wrote something like this> Right now I'm not able to test it because I don't have JVM in my machine. So I just wanted to know Is this correct implementation? Am I going in the right direction?

```
 import java.lang.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class Queue
{
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    LinkedList l1=new LinkedList();
    InputstreamReaderir=new InputstreamReader(System.in);
    BufferReader bf=new BufferReader(ir);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements to be inserted into queue");
    string str;
    str=bf.readline();
    System.out.println("Enter your Choice: ");
    System.out.println("1->Insert 2->Delete 3->Display 3->Exit");
    string choice;
    choice.readline();
    for(;;)
    {
        switch
        {
            case 1:l1.insertrear();
                   break;
            case 2:l1.deletefront();
                break;
            case 3: system.out("Contents of Queue are:" +l1);
                break;
            default: exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might find http://ideone.com helpful if you don't have a proper dev environment setup.

Comment: I don't really see a "queue" implementation here. You initialize a regular `LinkedList` and then attempt to call methods on it that don't exist.

Answer (score 5):

you're on the right track with using a `LinkedList`, this is one of the easiest ways to implement your own `Queue` - **I hope this is an exercise, since you should otherwise use Java's built-in `Queue`.**

I must confess I found your question interesting and decided to write a Queue so as to demonstrate. Note that you **should create a class** for your custom `Queue`. If you implement the whole thing in `main`, there'll be no way to *reuse* the code.

So you'd create a new file, let's call it `Queue.java`. It would look something like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Queue<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private LinkedList<T> elements = new LinkedList<T>();

    public void enqueue(T element) {
        elements.add(element);
    }

    public T dequeue() {
        return elements.removeFirst();
    }

    public T peek() {
        return elements.getFirst();
    }

    public void clear() {
        elements.clear();
    }

    public int size() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return elements.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return elements.iterator();
    }
}
```

Notice that that the code is *extremely* simple - no method's implementation is longer than one line. However, I don't know your level of experience so there might be two weird things in here: the use of [Generics](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0200__Generics/Catalog0200__Generics.htm) and the `implements Iterable<T>`.

#### [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

The `<T>` means you can put any Java object into the `Queue`*keeping Type safety*.
This means, when you call `Queue.Dequeue()`, the result will still have the same type that it had when you `Enqueued`
it.

#### [`Iterable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

Oracle says:

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the `foreach` statement.

Note that you don't need to know more, because we simply delegate this responsibility to `LinkedList.iterator()` which does the work for us.

Below is some code to test your new Queue. Play around with it. You can add other queue tests to `main`, for instance:

```
testQueue(true, false, true, true);
```

or

```
testQueue(0.5, 3.6, -5.4, 0.0);
```

to test putting different types of data into your `Queue`.
If anything remains unclear, feel free to leave a comment, and I'll update my answer.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testQueue(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        testQueue("first", "second", "third");
    }

    private static <T> void testQueue(T... elements) {
        outputLine("testing a Queue<%s>", getClassOf(elements));
        Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
        outputSize(queue);
        enqueueElementsInto(queue, elements);
        outputSize(queue);
        loopOverAllElementsOf(queue);
        dequeueAllFrom(queue);
        outputSize(queue);
        outputLine("---");
    }

    private static <T> void outputSize(Queue<T> queue) {
        outputLine("empty: %s, size: %s elements", queue.isEmpty(), queue.size());
    }

    private static <T> void enqueueElementsInto(Queue<T> queue, T... elements) {
        outputLine("enqueueing: ");
        for (T element : elements) {
            queue.enqueue(element);
            output(element + " ");
        }
    }

    private static <T> void loopOverAllElementsOf(Queue<T> queue) {
        outputLine("Queue contains: ");
        for (T element : queue) {
            output(element + " ");
        }
    }

    private static <T> void dequeueAllFrom(Queue<T> queue) {
        outputLine("dequeueing: ");
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            T next = queue.peek();
            T dequeued = queue.dequeue();
            outputLine("expected: %s ", next);
            output("dequeued: %s ", dequeued);
        }
    }

    private static void outputLine(String format, Object... params) {
        output('\n' + format, params);
    }

    private static void output(String format, Object... params) {
        System.out.print(String.format(format, params));
    }

    private static <T> String getClassOf(T... elements) {
        String nameOfArray = elements.getClass().getSimpleName();
        return nameOfArray.substring(0, nameOfArray.length() - 2);
    }
}
```

output:

> ```
> testing a Queue<Integer>
> empty: true, size: 0 elements
> enqueueing: 1 2 3 4 5 
> empty: false, size: 5 elements
> Queue contains: 1 2 3 4 5 
> dequeueing: 
> expected: 1 dequeued: 1 
> expected: 2 dequeued: 2 
> expected: 3 dequeued: 3 
> expected: 4 dequeued: 4 
> expected: 5 dequeued: 5 
> empty: true, size: 0 elements
> ---
> testing a Queue<String>
> empty: true, size: 0 elements
> enqueueing: first second third 
> empty: false, size: 3 elements
> Queue contains: first second third 
> dequeueing: 
> expected: first dequeued: first 
> expected: second dequeued: second 
> expected: third dequeued: third 
> empty: true, size: 0 elements
> ---
> ```

Comment: Very nice, but I would have liked to let student do a bit more of his homework.

Comment: @Chris thank you. Well, I just couldn't resist, I hadn't created a generic type in Java yet nor had I tried a simple Queue... curiosity got the better of me. Anyway, he'll have a hard time explaining this to his teacher if he doesn't understand it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It needs some improvement but you're definitely in the right direction. There are some typos (`string` should be `String`, for example) but I'm sure that you will be able to fix them.

Just two notes:

1, Here maybe you want to read some initial elements:

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of elements to be inserted into queue");
string str;
str=bf.readline();
```

2, The menu printing, input reading logic currently runs only once.